PIR sensor and its working
I have been designing a PIR sensor circuit for occupancy sensor. We have been facing problems like fault detections most of the time when we turn on air conditioning. There is also issues like the range of detection is more in one side and it is low in other side, I can't figure it out what's happening. If anyone has previous experience working on this please share some knowledge.

WHY THE SHOUTING IN THE TITLE?

I FIXED THE SHOUTING!

What sensor are you using?

i find that med/large ferrite beads around the supply leads and large caps across the supply at the module cut down on false positives.

I have been using D205B and LM324 for signal conditioning
